# Why arent my CSS styles being applied to on laptop media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-grid

My CSS styles arent being applied to my laptop size media query. I tried using a min and max width with no luck. Im looking to mimic this layout :

https://www.freshworks.com/crm/features/

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width:1199px){
  
 
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30vw);
    /* grid-template-rows: 430px 250px; */
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
 
   
  }
  .featureLeft{
    position: relative;
    right: -30px;
    
  }
  .featureRight{
    position: relative;
   left: 50px;
  }
  .marginBottom{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
   }

  .features{
    width:400px
  }
  
  p{
    font-size: 16px; 
  }
  h1{
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  h2{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    
    
  }
  .grid-container>div {
  
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px
 
 
  } 

  .container {   
     width: 90%;  
     margin-left: 10px;
     
    } 

  .the-feed {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 ;
    margin-left: 160px;
    
  }

  .feed-image{
   height: 305px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
   right: 30px
  } 

}




/* desktop styles */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  
  
  
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30vw);
    /* grid-template-rows: 430px 250px; */
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    

    
   
  }


  .featureLeft{
    position: relative;
    right: -30px;
    
  }
  .featureRight{
    position: relative;
   left: 50px;
  }
  .marginBottom{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
   }

  .features{
    width:400px
  }
  
  p{
    font-size: 16px; 
  }
  h1{
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  h2{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    
    
  }
  .grid-container>div {
  
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px
 
 
  } 

  .container {   
     width: 1300px;  
     margin-left: 20px;
     
    } 

  .the-feed {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 ;
    margin-left: 160px;
    
  }

  .feed-image{
   height: 305px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
   right: 30px
  } 

}
```

Ive got the grid working but it seems to spaced on my desktop, when I move the features closer together, laptop size messes up even though I have seperate media queries

heres my codepen : https://codepen.io/shuibcodes/pen/xxqWajO

Comment: is it me or do the styles look exactly the same in both media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your laptop media query styles are applied but they not seem to be styled correctly for the reference you shared.

Check these fixes.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50vw); //Changed
    
    ....

   .the-feed {
    grid-column: 1/-1; //Changed
  }
```

Full example : https://codepen.io/AravinthAro/pen/gOmeqjJ